# Jquery datatables - Pass current page number to Ajax URL

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the latest datatables and have a datable specified this way. How can I pass the current page number to the ajax URL? I have specified `"this.page()"`, but it doesn't recognize it as a valid function.

```
 var table = $("#userList").DataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": "true",
    "bAutoWidth": "false",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100],
    "aaSorting": [],
    "processing": "true",
    "serverSide": "true",
    "ajax":$.fn.dataTable.pipeline( { 
              url: "/server/users?page="+this.page(), 
              pages: 5 
     } ),
    "bSortClasses": "false",
    "aoColumns": [
                  { "sWidth": "6%"},{ "sWidth": "10%"},
                  { "sWidth": "20%"},{ "sWidth": "15%"},
                  { "sWidth": "15%"},{ "sWidth": "30%"}],
    "sDom": "<\"H\"<>C<\"#exportOptions\">fr><\"datatable-scroll\"t><\"F\"lip>",        
    "oColVis": {
                 "aiExclude": [ 0, 1 ],
    "buttonText": "Show/Hide Columns  <img src='/images/arrow.png'>",
    "bRestore": true
               },

    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                            }
                     } );
```

Comment: How about page.info()? https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

Comment: I think it requires it to declare after the .Datatable() function. I was looking for something I can add inside the .Datatable() function